# Python - Perform file check based on format of 3 values then perform tasks

Tags: python

All,

I am trying to write a python script that will go through a crime file and separate the file based on the following items: UPDATES, INCIDENTS, and ARRESTS. The reports that I generally receive either show these sections as I have previously listed or by **UPDATES**, **INCIDENTS**, or **ARRESTS**. I have already started to write the following script to separate the files based on the following format with the **. However, I was wondering if there was a better way to check the files for both formats at the same time? Also, sometimes there is not an UPDATES or ARRESTS section which causes my code to break. I was wondering if there is a check I can do for this instance, and if this is the case, how can I still get the INCIDENTS section without the other two?

```
with open('CrimeReport20150518.txt', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
  print content.index('**UPDATES**')
  print content.index('**INCIDENTS**')
  print content.index('**ARRESTS**')
  updatesLine = content.index('**UPDATES**')
  incidentsLine = content.index('**INCIDENTS**')
  arrestsLine = content.index('**ARRESTS**')
  #print content[updatesLine:incidentsLine]
  updates = content[updatesLine:incidentsLine]
  #print updates
  incidents = content[incidentsLine:arrestsLine]
  #print incidents
  arrests = content[arrestsLine:]
  print arrests
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using [`.index()`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) to locate the headings in the text.  The documentation states:

> Like find(), but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.

That means that you need to catch the exception in order to handle it.  For example:

```
try:
    updatesLine = content.index('**UPDATES**')
    print "Found updates heading at", updatesLine
except ValueError:
    print "Note: no updates"
    updatesLine = -1
```

From here you can determine the correct indexes for slicing the string based on which sections are present.

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`.find()`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method referenced in the documentation for `.index()`.

> Return -1 if sub is not found.

Using find you can just test the value it returned.

```
updatesLine = content.find('**UPDATES**')
# the following is straightforward, but unwieldy
if updatesLine != -1:
    if incidentsLine != -1:
        updates = content[updatesLine:incidentsLine]
    elif arrestsLine != -1:
        updates = content[updatesLine:arrestsLine]
    else:
        updates = content[updatesLine:]
```

---

---

Either way, you'll have to deal with all combinations of which sections are and are not present to determine the correct slice boundaries.

I would prefer to approach this using a state machine.  Read the file line by line and add the line to the appropriate list.  When a header is found then update the state.  Here is an untested demonstration of the principle:

```
data = {
    'updates': [],
    'incidents':  [],
    'arrests': [],
    }

state = None
with open('CrimeReport20150518.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == '**UPDATES**':
            state = 'updates'
        elif line == '**INCIDENTS**':
            state = 'incidents'
        elif line == '**ARRESTS**':
            state = 'arrests'
        else:
            if state is None:
                print "Warn: no header seen; skipping line"
            else
                data[state].append(line)

print data['arrests'].join('')
```

Comment: A state machine is definitely the best approach. You could even generalize it so you don't have to name the sections in advance; it could derive those from the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `content.find()` instead of `content.index()`. Instead of breaking when the string isn't there, it returns -1. Then you can do something like this:

```
updatesLine = content.find('**UPDATES**')
incidentsLine = content.find('**INCIDENTS**')
arrestsLine = content.find('**ARRESTS**')

if incidentsLine != -1 and arrestsLine != -1:

       # Do what you normally do
       updatesLine = content.index('**UPDATES**')
       incidentsLine = content.index('**INCIDENTS**')
       arrestsLine = content.index('**ARRESTS**')

       updates = content[updatesLine:incidentsLine]
       incidents = content[incidentsLine:arrestsLine]
       arrests = content[arrestsLine:]

elif incidentsLine != -1:
     # Do whatever you need to do to files that don't have an arrests section here

elif arreststsLine != -1:
     # Handle files that don't have an incidents section here

else:
     # Handle files that are missing both
```

Probably you'll need to handle all four possible combinations slightly differently.

Your solution generally looks OK to me as long as the sections always come in the same order and the files don't get too big. You can get real feedback at stack exchange's code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/